# Is there an easier way to produce a numpy matrix where the numbers worm up and down vertically

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm sorry I don't know the correct terminology hence 'worm vertically' basically I want the numbers to start at the bottom left and as it goes up the column it adds, then the next column has its lowest number at the top and adds as it goes down. eg:

```
[2, 3, 8
 1, 4, 7
 0, 5, 6]
```

so far I came up with this very bloated code that basically makes a column then copies it, flips it, adds the max value of the last column plus 1, then hstack's them together eg:

first column

```
[2,
 1,
 0,]
```

flip it:

```
[0,
 1,
 2,]
```

add the max value of the last plus 1 (3 in this case):

```
 [3,
  4,
  5,]
```

hstack them:

```
[2, 3
 1, 4
 0, 5]
```

I then just repeat this for as many columns I want. to speed things up, if I wanted 4 I can just take the final hstack and copy both columns and add the max value. no flipping is needed because its an even number of columns.

The matrix I need has 252 items in a 12 by 21 matrix. This is the code I have so far:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(20,-1,-1).reshape(21,1)
b = a+1 + a[::-1]*2
c = b+1 + a*2
d = np.hstack((a,b,c))
e = np.hstack((d,np.flip(d,0)+ d.shape[0] * d.shape[1]))
f = np.hstack((e,e + e.shape[0] * e.shape[1]))
del a,b,c,d,e

>>> f
array([[ 20,  21,  62,  63, 104, 105, 146, 147, 188, 189, 230, 231],
       [ 19,  22,  61,  64, 103, 106, 145, 148, 187, 190, 229, 232],
       [ 18,  23,  60,  65, 102, 107, 144, 149, 186, 191, 228, 233],
       [ 17,  24,  59,  66, 101, 108, 143, 150, 185, 192, 227, 234],
       [ 16,  25,  58,  67, 100, 109, 142, 151, 184, 193, 226, 235],
       [ 15,  26,  57,  68,  99, 110, 141, 152, 183, 194, 225, 236],
       [ 14,  27,  56,  69,  98, 111, 140, 153, 182, 195, 224, 237],
       [ 13,  28,  55,  70,  97, 112, 139, 154, 181, 196, 223, 238],
       [ 12,  29,  54,  71,  96, 113, 138, 155, 180, 197, 222, 239],
       [ 11,  30,  53,  72,  95, 114, 137, 156, 179, 198, 221, 240],
       [ 10,  31,  52,  73,  94, 115, 136, 157, 178, 199, 220, 241],
       [  9,  32,  51,  74,  93, 116, 135, 158, 177, 200, 219, 242],
       [  8,  33,  50,  75,  92, 117, 134, 159, 176, 201, 218, 243],
       [  7,  34,  49,  76,  91, 118, 133, 160, 175, 202, 217, 244],
       [  6,  35,  48,  77,  90, 119, 132, 161, 174, 203, 216, 245],
       [  5,  36,  47,  78,  89, 120, 131, 162, 173, 204, 215, 246],
       [  4,  37,  46,  79,  88, 121, 130, 163, 172, 205, 214, 247],
       [  3,  38,  45,  80,  87, 122, 129, 164, 171, 206, 213, 248],
       [  2,  39,  44,  81,  86, 123, 128, 165, 170, 207, 212, 249],
       [  1,  40,  43,  82,  85, 124, 127, 166, 169, 208, 211, 250],
       [  0,  41,  42,  83,  84, 125, 126, 167, 168, 209, 210, 251]])
```

Is there a super simple way of doing this that I'm not seeing or don't know?

Comment: FWIW, the technical term for this sort of "worming" arrangement is ["boustrophedon"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boustrophedon) or "boustrophedonic".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [transpose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) the array and [flip vertically](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flipud.html) every second column:

```
import numpy as np
row = 4
col = 5
a = np.transpose(np.arange(row * col).reshape(col, row))
a[:, ::2] = np.flipud(a[:, ::2])

print(a)
#Output
[[ 3  4 11 12 19]
 [ 2  5 10 13 18]
 [ 1  6  9 14 17]
 [ 0  7  8 15 16]]
```

There is of course also a [horizontal version of this flip function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fliplr.html#numpy.fliplr).

Comment: Now why didn't I think of that. I guess it's because I didn't know about `flipud`.  :) Nice work.

Comment: How strange, I find your solution more elegant.

Comment: Thanks a bunch that is 100x more easy than my solution.

Comment: Looks like the OP prefers yours, though. Which is perfectly ok. I suppose we should do a timeit test to see which one's faster...

Answer (score 5):

Sure, you can do this with slicing. Use transposition to fill the array vertically instead of horizontally, and then use slicing to reverse the direction of the even columns.

```
import numpy as np

rows, cols = 21, 12
a = np.arange(rows * cols).reshape(cols, rows).transpose()
b = np.arange(0, cols, 2)
a[:, b] = a[::-1, b]
print(a)
```

**output**

```
[[ 20  21  62  63 104 105 146 147 188 189 230 231]
 [ 19  22  61  64 103 106 145 148 187 190 229 232]
 [ 18  23  60  65 102 107 144 149 186 191 228 233]
 [ 17  24  59  66 101 108 143 150 185 192 227 234]
 [ 16  25  58  67 100 109 142 151 184 193 226 235]
 [ 15  26  57  68  99 110 141 152 183 194 225 236]
 [ 14  27  56  69  98 111 140 153 182 195 224 237]
 [ 13  28  55  70  97 112 139 154 181 196 223 238]
 [ 12  29  54  71  96 113 138 155 180 197 222 239]
 [ 11  30  53  72  95 114 137 156 179 198 221 240]
 [ 10  31  52  73  94 115 136 157 178 199 220 241]
 [  9  32  51  74  93 116 135 158 177 200 219 242]
 [  8  33  50  75  92 117 134 159 176 201 218 243]
 [  7  34  49  76  91 118 133 160 175 202 217 244]
 [  6  35  48  77  90 119 132 161 174 203 216 245]
 [  5  36  47  78  89 120 131 162 173 204 215 246]
 [  4  37  46  79  88 121 130 163 172 205 214 247]
 [  3  38  45  80  87 122 129 164 171 206 213 248]
 [  2  39  44  81  86 123 128 165 170 207 212 249]
 [  1  40  43  82  85 124 127 166 169 208 211 250]
 [  0  41  42  83  84 125 126 167 168 209 210 251]]
```